# Получение общего количества успешных сделок у менеджеров - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Из вводных данных: таблица `orders`, поле `manager_id` - id менеджера, `status = 10` - сделка успешна. Цель - мотивация менеджеров через геймификацию.

Понимаю, что для получения всех успешных сделок выбираем всех менеджеров + COUNT() от сделок с их ID через джоин. Как мне отслеживать изменение позиции менеджера? К примеру, менеджер A завершил сделку и опередил менеджера Б по кол-ву завершенных сделок. Каким образом мне это отследить? Лучше это сделать через CRON, к примеру, каждые 10 минут? Или же делать какой-то условный "переучет" после каждой закрытой сделки?

Answer (score 2):

Отвечаю на Ваши вопросы:

**Вопрос:**"Как мне отслеживать изменение позиции менеджера? К примеру, менеджер A завершил сделку и опередил менеджера Б по кол-ву завершенных сделок. Каким образом мне это отследить?"

**Ответ:** сделайте обратную сортировку по количеству сделок, используя ваши условия (ORDER BY "Количество сделок" DESC). На первом месте будет тот, у кого сделок больше.

**Вопрос:** Лучше это сделать через CRON, к примеру, каждые 10 минут? Или же делать какой-то условный "переучет" после каждой закрытой сделки?

**Ответ:** Если по каким-либо причинам невозможно использовать встроенные механизмы СУБД - используйте CRON.